# Fitz (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frontend') error in docker

Tags: python, pdf

I am getting this error that:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frontend' once I am trying to import fitz in my docker application.

Tried using:

- fitz==0.0.1.dev2
- PyMuPDF==1.16.14
  But still the same problem is there.

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem with these 2 packages.
I used these 2 lines and it solved my problem:

```
pip install fitz
pip install pip install PyMuPDF==1.19.0
```

the problem is that the latest version of PyMuPDF is not compatible with fitz.