# Insert image in pdf file using python

Tags: python, image, pdf

I want to insert an image in a pdf using a python script. I have given a jpg as well as a png file. I want to be able to specify a page number, x and y coordinates and heigth and width of the image. Then I want the image inserted at the given point.

I have found this question: [How to add image to PDF file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276409/how-to-add-image-to-pdf-file-in-python), but the answer is only providing a way to overlay another pdf page on an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with PyMuPDF.

Here is a sample code but I didn't tested.

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import fitz

input_file = "example.pdf"
output_file = "example-with-barcode.pdf"
barcode_file = "barcode.png"

# define the position (upper-right corner)
image_rectangle = fitz.Rect(450,20,550,120)

# retrieve the first page of the PDF
file_handle = fitz.open(input_file)
first_page = file_handle[0]

# add the image
first_page.insertImage(image_rectangle, fileName=barcode_file)

file_handle.save(output_file)
```

Comment: Ths worked, but I had to change the PyMuPdf version first as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68483853/fitz-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-frontend-error-in-docker.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using the PyMuPDF package:

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")  # your input PDF
pno = 17  # the desired page number, 0-based
rect = (x, y, x + width, y + height)  # the rectangle showing the image
imgpath = "some.png"  # image filename, supports all popular formats

page = doc[pno]  # load desired page in the PDF
page.insert_image(rect, filename=imgpath)

doc.ez_save("output.pdf")  # save new version of the PDF
```

Points to consider:

- The `rect` will show the image ***centered***: image center and rect center will be the same. Only if `width` / `height` have the same aspect ratio as the image, you will get what you want.
- You can choose to rotate the image by a multiple of 90 degrees.
- You can choose to put the image in foreground (default) or background.

Comment: Ah, https://stackoverflow.com/users/3661220/dananjaya has posted something similar at the same time! 